# Segmentation fault (core dumped). Где ошибка?

Tags: c, ubuntu, файлы, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    if(argv[1]==NULL) 
        printf("Synopsis: %s output_file\n",argv[0]);
    else
    {
        file = fopen(argv[0],"a+");
        if (file != NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: can't open file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            char *s=malloc(10*sizeof(*s));
            s="^F";
            for (char c = getc(stdin); c != 's'; c = getc(stdin))
                {
                    fputc(c, file );
                }
            free(s);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему вы не используете отладчик? Ваша задача для начала выяснить, в какой строке падает ваша программа, и чему равны значения переменных в этой строке.

Comment: Хотя присваивание строке нового значения после malloc'а наталкивает на определённые мысли. Какую книгу по C вы читали? Это плохая книга, прочитайте другую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имеется несколько ошибок.
Сначала вы проверяете, задан ли параметр при вызове программы

```
if(argv[1]==NULL) 
       ^^^
    printf("Synopsis: %s output_file\n",argv[0]);
```

А затем пытаетесь открыть файл вашей собственной программы вместо файла, заданного первым параметром

```
    file = fopen(argv[0],"a+");
                     ^^^
```

Если файл не был открыт, то функция `fopen` вернет нулевой указатель. Поэтому вместо условия в данном if предложении

```
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

должно быть другое условие

```
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Затем вы зачем-то выделяете память под символьный массив

```
        char *s=malloc(10*sizeof(*s));
```

который нигде не используется. И тут же указатель переприсваиваете адресом строкового литерала

```
        s="^F";
```

в результате чего у вас происходит утечка памяти.

И более того в этом предложении

```
free(s);
```

вы пытаетесь освободить память строкового литерала, которая имеет статическую длительность. Что также может привести к неопределенному поведению программы.

Данный цикл

```
       for (char c = getc(stdin); c != 's'; c = getc(stdin))
            {
                fputc(c, file );
            }
```

также не корректный, так как функция `getc` может вернуть значение `EOF`, которое вы в условии цикла не проверяете.